# Saving barcode result into the clipboard - Android app

Tags: java, android, textview, clipboard, barcode-scanner

I have created a barcode scanner which returns the resulting numbers into a textview to show the user the result.

I have added a button which will take the user to a barcode lookup website so that the barcode can be searched to identify the product.  Ideally, I would love it to do this automatically when the barcode is scanned but as I think that may be a bit beyond my current level of expertise, I would like to be able to get the resulting barcode numbers to be automatically added to the clipboard so that when the user goes to the website, all they have to do is paste the number into the relevant field.

The code for the barcode result is below where 'barcodeResult' is the textview:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            if (data != null) {
                Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
                barcodeResult.setText("Barcode value : "+barcode.displayValue);
            } else {
                barcodeResult.setText("No barcode found");
            }

        } else {

        }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

public void browser1 (View view) {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.barcodelookup.com/api"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

EDIT:  I've tried adding the below into the if statement where the result is !null:

```
final ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(this.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                clipboardManager.setText((CharSequence) barcodeResult);
```

but this is giving me the error:

```
android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

I'm not sure where I can go from here as I don't fully understand the error.

Any advice greatly appreciated as always.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After discovering that the error I was getting is because you can't use CharSequence with a TextView, I found some code for the ClipboardManager that I could use and changed the TextView to EditText.  The resulting code is below (full IF statement):

```
if (data != null) {
                Barcode barcode = data.getParcelableExtra("barcode");
                barcodeResult.setText(barcode.displayValue);
                final ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(this.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", barcodeResult.getText().toString() );
                clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Result added to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Changing to and EditText box does change the look of my app and how I wanted it to function but it is workable.